# Define relationship between tables without defining models in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have to make relationship between tables in Sequelize. I have tables in PostgreSQL but do not have model defined.

Is there a way to define relationship without defining model first?

Comment: What's the benefit having relationsships w/o models? How will you plan to use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, There is a way to auto generate models. I generate models using forest admin.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).